# Use of "In the Middle" to describe an ongoing description

Tags: word-usage

If I write this:

In the middle of my return to our dormitories,

Do you see anything wrong with it? A friend was pointing out the use of the word "middle" , but I think it can be used to describe ongoing actions also, not only places.

I'm also not sure about the "my return part". Maybe " In the middle of me going back to our dormitories" Or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Your examples are not wrong, but they are not that usual - they are a tad too long.

Unless you really need to say "middle" for whatever reason, you are better saying:

> **While** returning to our dormitories ...

Answer (score 1):

"I was in the middle of doing my taxes when the phone rang."

"In the middle of" (as I think you are using it) is useful when you want to emphasize that something happened while you were doing something else.